# Zeppelin how to view or merge the data from multiple source

Tags: interpreter, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to read the data from multiple sources and merge in Zeppelin?

For example two different interpreters JDBC1 and JDBC2 point to different databases. JDBC1 based notebook can get the user name and phone for user-id, and JDBC2 can get the other details of a user.
Need to merge this data at the UI side to display in a graph or table.

```
 "python": {
  "id": "python",
  "name": "python",
  "group": "python",
  "properties": {
    "zeppelin.python": {
      "name": "zeppelin.python",
      "value": "/usr/bin/python3.5",
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Python binary executable path. It is set to python by default.(assume python is in your $PATH)"
    },
    "zeppelin.python.maxResult": {
      "name": "zeppelin.python.maxResult",
      "value": "1000",
      "type": "number",
      "description": "Max number of dataframe rows to display."
    },
    "zeppelin.python.useIPython": {
      "name": "zeppelin.python.useIPython",
      "value": true,
      "type": "checkbox",
      "description": "Whether use IPython when it is available in `%python`"
    },
    "zeppelin.ipython.launch.timeout": {
      "name": "zeppelin.ipython.launch.timeout",
      "value": "30000",
      "type": "number",
      "description": "Time out for ipython launch"
    },
    "zeppelin.ipython.grpc.message_size": {
      "name": "zeppelin.ipython.grpc.message_size",
      "value": "33554432",
      "type": "number",
      "description": "grpc message size, default is 32M"
    }
  },
  "status": "READY",
  "interpreterGroup": [
    {
      "name": "python",
      "class": "org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter",
      "defaultInterpreter": true,
      "editor": {
        "language": "python",
        "editOnDblClick": false,
        "completionSupport": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ipython",
      "class": "org.apache.zeppelin.python.IPythonInterpreter",
      "defaultInterpreter": false,
      "editor": {
        "language": "python",
        "editOnDblClick": false,
        "completionKey": "TAB",
        "completionSupport": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "sql",
      "class": "org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreterPandasSql",
      "defaultInterpreter": false,
      "editor": {
        "language": "sql",
        "editOnDblClick": false,
        "completionKey": "TAB",
        "completionSupport": false
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "conda",
      "class": "org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonCondaInterpreter",
      "defaultInterpreter": false,
      "editor": {
        "language": "sh",
        "editOnDblClick": false,
        "completionSupport": false
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "docker",
      "class": "org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonDockerInterpreter",
      "defaultInterpreter": false,
      "editor": {
        "language": "sh",
        "editOnDblClick": false,
        "completionSupport": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": [],
  "option": {
    "remote": true,
    "port": -1,
    "perNote": "shared",
    "perUser": "shared",
    "isExistingProcess": false,
    "setPermission": false,
    "owners": [],
    "isUserImpersonate": false
  }
}
```